# How can reference by pods files in Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift

My problem is 'CustomTrashCan.swift'. How can I reference by pods files?

[image]

Comment: Build your project and import the module(s) you want to reference.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed  Because i want modify the blockly project applied to myself project.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, thank you. how can import the module?

Comment: The same way as you import UIKit. Just write `import ModuleName`

Comment: @Sweeper  thank you, In pods files don't import custom class name,so this way won't work.I think my custom files and pods files is not in the same project.

Comment: Don't import the class name. Import the module name.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you very much. I understand now. I'm try it.